# apostrophe is not correctly rendered in IE

Tags: javascript

I have some html content with apostrophe inside a div, It renders correctly in all other browsers other than IE. You will get a clear idea from the screen-shot

On other browsers

[image]

On IE

[image]

I have searched enough and found issues like apostrophe shown as `&apos;`. I think this is not similar to that issue.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Post the page source. First of all, fonts seem to be different on screenshots. Second, which encoding used in meta tag and the file?

Comment: Did you [specify the character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)?

Comment: I never understood why people would want to use a right single quotation mark for an apostrophe anyway.

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev its UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page needs `utf-8` headers. Your server should be serving pages with:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

Or you can place it with a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Or just serve your content with html entities instead

```
He&apos;s not feeling well.
```

Comment: `&apos;` is a normal apostrophe, so you can just as well write `He's`. The OP's question had a quotation mark, `&#x2019;`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, IE has not been told to use UTF-8 encoding. I believe it's in the menu `View`>`Encoding` but there should also be a `<meta>` tag specifying it in the page.

Comment: @Jeevan: So we're down to a guessing game. Edit your question to include a link to a page which actually demonstrates the problem.